# how to disable shard re-balancing in elastic search, while allowing new indices to be allocated?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch version 1.0.1 and want to achieve two things at the same time - 
1. Allow new indices to be created ( the primary and replica shards need to be allocated as per usual logic). 
2. Prevent existing shards to be rebalanced on node failure.

What combination of settings will allow me to achieve the same? I tried the settings from the cluster module documented at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-cluster.html. But I am unable to achieve both of them at the same time.

Thanks,